# Integral curves in the plane

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

Maybe this is a stupid question but i can not solve this mechanical problem...

How can I find the integral curves of the vector field

$$X_{(x,y)} = x \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} − y\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} = \begin{bmatrix}x \\  -y\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Comment: do you need the analytic solutions? If that is the case you have an uncoupled system which can be solved. one equation is $\dot x=x$  and the other is $\dot y=-y$. In case you only need the phase portrait note that you have a linear system, and the eigenvalues are ${-1,1}$ so you have a saddle.

Comment: If $x \ne 0, y \ne 0$, then
$$\begin{cases}x' = x\\y' = -y\end{cases} \implies \frac{x'}{x} + \frac{y'}{y} = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dt}\log(xy) = 0 \implies xy = \text{constant}$$
You need to handle the special case $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ separately but that is relatively easy.

Comment: Seemingly contrary to all current answers, I see this as 
$$u_x=u,\quad v_y=v.$$
What am I missing?
Actually, left multiplication by a column vector is really throwing me. How does this notation work?

Comment: @Brady: This is an ODE for a curve. Who are your $u$ and $v$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, $u$ and $v$ would be the components of the function ${\bf u}(x,y)$ that the operator is acting on.

Comment: So then the curve is some implicit $u(x,y)=c$?

Comment: Oh, I forgot, you are using the association of partials with vectors... I'll temporarily ignore the vector to read. So we're missing an "equals zero" bit.

Comment: @Brady: It is standard notation in the theory of manifolds to use $\partial/\partial x$,  $\partial/\partial y$ to indicate the basis for the tangent space (here, $\Bbb R^2$). Tangent vectors act on smooth functions by directional derivatives, but they are still tangent vectors! :)

Comment: Reviewing manifolds is somewhere on my todo list. Backing away slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the integral curves satisfy

$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}' = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ -y \end{bmatrix}, \tag{1}$

so we've got

$x' = x \tag{2}$

and

$y' = -y; \tag{3}$

the solutions of (2) and (3) are

$x(t) = x_0 e^t \tag{4}$

and

$y(t) = y_0e^{-t}, \tag{5}$

where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are the values of $x$ and $y$ at $t = 0$.  And that just about does it, doesn't it?!???!?

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Seems to me you could have noticed my response eight minutes ahead of yours and let the OP do the Calculus I for himself.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You need to solve the (already decoupled) system $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = x$, $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = -y$.